# Creating shapekeys for a mesh using constraints applied to a different meshes shapekeys

Tags: constraints, shape-keys

More or less I am trying to create shape keys for a new object that make it follow the location, rotation, and general scale of another mesh's shape keys. I am attempting to do this using constraints, but I am now realizing that constraints is only moving the origin, and not the actual geometry, so I cannot make this work out of the gate. I've spent the better part of the night looking for some information on this, and cannot find anything. It ***seems*** like this should be something simple to do.

I thought to try applying visual transformation and just creating meshes for each individual shape key, but I have no idea how to make a shape key that combines 2 objects. I'm sure someone knows something about this, or has attempted to do this. (Even if this did work I think it would be quite a tedious process just to attach a spike to 150 shape keys of animation)

Basically imagine you have an animated mesh that animates 100% off of shape keys (without bones or anything else) not because you choose to but because it is the framework that you were given and you need to attach a spike to part of the arm (a vertex group target), and have the mesh separate and exportable with all the shape keys matching those in the target mesh.

Don't know if anyone has any input on this or how it might be solved, but I would definitely appreciate it, and would certainly save a major headache for me and anyone else who may need to do something like this. Perhaps I'm going about this problem the wrong way, and there is some friendlier method for such a thing already in blender I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

In my example I selected the sphere, selected 3 vertices in edit mode, in object mode I selected the empty, shift selected the sphere, pressed Ctrl P, 3 vertex (triangle) option.

Now the empty follows the transformations of those 3 vertices, even if rotated, scaled or modified by shape keys.

The reverse of this is the Hook modifier: the empty can control another object as a whole with parenting, or it can influence a vertex group only, using a hook modifier pointing at the empty.

Hope it can be useful in your case.

[image]